# Why various syntaxes for various commands?

Tags: syntax, parsing

I understand that the standard syntax of commands in TeX is

```
\name[optional-1]…[optional-n]{argument-1}…{argument-n}
```

The `tabular` environment, however, apparently takes its optional arguments after the required arguments, while `item` and `hskip`/`vskip` have their arguments after a space and not grouped in any way.

Why the inconsistency? Are there any more commands like `tabular`, `item`,a and the `skip`’s?

Comment: The optional argument to `tabular` goes just after `\begin{tabular}`, not after the mandatory argument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your initial understanding is incorrect. The `[]` convention for optional arguments is a *LaTeX* convention. One of the aims of LaTeX is to give a consistent command interface over the TeX primitives which have wildly inconsistent syntax.

For primitives:

`\over` is  *infix*   `{a \over b}` so LaTeX provides `\frac{a}{b}`

`hskip` is weird with the argument not delimited at all other than by the grammar for a length `\hskip 0pt plus 3pt xxx`  LaTeX provides `\hspace{0pt plus 3pt}xxx`

However it is best to avoid having multiple optional arguments adjacent to each other. If the command is

```
\name[opt1][opt2]{main}
```

Then you can not supply the second option without supplying the first, but if the syntax is

```
\name[opt1]{main}[opt2]
```

Both optional arguments may be independently omitted.

See for example `\newcounter` or `\newtheorem` which have multiple options.

This soon gets out of hand so most modern packages if they want more options switch to a keyval system

```
\name[opt1=aaa,opt2=bbb]{main}
```

The standard LaTeX `\newcommand` only allows defining one optional argument, which must be the first argument, to avoid such problems.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it explains a lot. I so wish TeX were more consistent that I must have forced my own wish on the actual state of things. Good to have it cleared up!

Answer (score 10):

You're making wrong assumptions, I'm afraid.

TeX has no notion of optional arguments in brackets and its syntax is, to say the least, not standardized. Some examples of TeX primitives:

- `\hbox` has optional arguments that specify the width of the box or how much spaces in the box should be spread out; so the cases are

  ```
  \hbox{<material>}
  \hbox to <dimen>{<material>}
  \hbox spread <dimen>{<material>}
  ```
- the argument to `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\vtop`, `\halign` and `\valign` can be enclosed by `\bgroup` and `\egroup`; this is not allowed for the argument to `\uppercase`, `\lowercase`, where the left delimiter can be `\bgroup`, but the right delimiter *has* to be `}`
- `\vrule` has optional arguments specifying the width, height and depth; these are introduced by the keywords `width`, `height` and `depth` and there can be any number of them, the last specified win
- `\hskip` has optional arguments specifying the stretchability and shrinkability, introduced by the keywords `plus` and `minus`; but `plus <dimen>`, if present,  *must* go before a `minus <dimen>` specification. It's not allowed to have multiple instances of the keywords.
- `\over` applies to everything preceding and following it in the (sub)formula it appears in, taking what precedes as the numerator and what follows as the denominator

Apart from the last case (which is a wrong decision made by Knuth), the way arguments are specified has its logic, though understanding it requires a rather deep knowledge of the TeXbook. In some cases the argument is delimited by braces, in others it isn't. The idea is that primitive commands are not supposed to be used in documents and so their syntax is peculiar for greater efficiency.

Plain TeX also sports a non standard syntax:

- for the cubic root of 27 you have to say `$\root 3\of{27}$`
- the argument to `\beginsection` is everything up to the first blank line (or explicit `\par`)
- the first argument to `\proclaim` is whatever precedes the first period and the second argument is everything from there up to the first blank line

LaTeX tries to set up conventions that are as uniform as possible. For instance, `\makebox` has two optional arguments and a mandatory one; the order is

```
\makebox[<dimen>][<alignment>]{<material>}
```

where the second optional argument doesn't make sense if the first is absent. Instead, `\newtheorem` has two optional arguments and two mandatory ones:

```
\newtheorem{<envname>}[<counter>]{<name>}[<counter>]
```

where *only one* optional argument can appear. If the first appears, it tells what counter should be used for the numbering of `<envname>`; the final optional argument specifies instead a “parent counter”. This is similar to the syntax for `\newcounter`:

```
\newcounter{<name>}[<counter>]
```

where the presence of the optional argument means that the newly defined counter should be reset when  is stepped and numbered within it; an example is `\newcounter{subsection}[section]`. So

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
```

means that `thm` and `prop` share the same counter, which is reset any time `section` is stepped and will have the representation `<section number><thm number>`.

You mention `\item`, which has an optional argument and *no* mandatory argument; the text following it is not passed to `\item` as an argument. Environments follow the same conventions, but the arguments follow `\begin{<env>}`; for instance

```
\begin{tabular}[<alignment>]{<columns>}
```

has, as usual, the optional argument before the mandatory one. In LaTeX only a handful of primitives have their use and are documented in the manual; none of them takes arguments (`\par`, `\hfil`, `\hfill`, `\vfil` and `\vfill`, IIRC).

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! I didn't realize just how inconsistent TeX was. It's such a shame it's so mingled. Oh well, I guess every rose must have its thorns.

Comment: @KamilS. It's not *really* inconsistent; but you have to guess the rules yourself, the TeXbook only show the syntax. But it's a rewarding job.